# Displaying firebase information based on search query [Firebase][Swift]

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Database whereby I'm trying to display 5 random users (with their name and email) by querying them by their age, on 5 different view controllers which are controlled by a UIPageViewController.

I have created the query code to display users by their age. The code is below:

```
func findoutinfo(){
    let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users")

    let query = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "Age").queryEqual(toValue: "21")
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = childSnap.value as! [String: Any]

            let name = dict["Name"] as! String
            let email = dict["email"] as! String

            print(childSnap.key, name, email)
        }
    })
}
```

However, I haven't discovered a way of randomly picking 5 users and display their information on the various pages. Ensuring that all of them are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately. Firebase doesn't provide you with a simple solution for picking random children. Depending on the use case you might have to go for different approaches.

If the list of Users isn't big, you can get all the users, put them in an array and then pick 5 of them randomly. Something like:

```
var selectedUsers = [[String: Any]]() 
let qtyOfUsersToSelect = 5
var users = getUsersArrayFromFirebase() // Made up function where you should fetch the Users.
for i in 1...5 {
    selectedUsers.append(users.remove(at: Int.random(0..<users.count)))
}
```

If you expect the database users to be big, then I would recommend you using Firebase functions and handling this on the backend.

Comment: Firstly thank you for your response. I'm expecting more than 5000 users so I don't think It'll work to call all the users. I was thinking implementing an age child node inside the user node where by it adds users of that particular age. Then use a function to get 5 values from the particular age node. Do you think that will work?

Comment: it might be a solution but bear in mind people have the obsession of updating their age every year. And this might happen every day, so it might generate undesirable overload.